# How to extract counterid from below JSON data only if counter_name is matched and add the counterid to another file in shell script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, yaml

I am writing in shellscript.

I have a JSON data. I need to extract the counterid and pass that data to a .yml file. I want to replace data in the yml file if counter_name (in the JSON data) is matched with the data in the yml file and replace with it counterid.

Example:

```
{"counterId" : 200001 ,"counterName" = status-total_access"}
```

Original yml file:

```
- rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.total_kbytes"
        to: "apache.status-total_kbytes"
```

yml file should be changed as:

```
- rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.total_kbytes"
        to: "apache.2000001"
```

So, is there any way to do it in shellscript?

I know there is an option called sed, but don't know how to extract the JSON values.

This is my json data:

```
[{"counterId":200001,"counterName":"status-total_accesses"},{"counterId":200002,"counterName":"status-total_kbytes"},{"counterId":200003,"counterName":"status-requests_per_sec"},{"counterId":200004,"counterName":"status-bytes_per_sec"},{"counterId":200005,"counterName":"status-bytes_per_request"},{"counterId":200006,"counterName":"workers-busy"}]
```

This is my yml file:

```
- rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.workers.busy"
        to: "apache.workers-busy"  
     ignore_missing: true   
 - rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.workers.idle"
        to:  "apache.workers-idle"
     ignore_missing: true   
 - rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.total_accesses"
        to: "apache.status-total_accesses"
     ignore_missing: true
 - rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.total_kbytes"
        to: "apache.status-total_kbytes"
     ignore_missing: true   
 - rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.uptime.server_uptime"
        to: "apache.uptime-server_uptime"
     ignore_missing: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need something like jq. Using jq you will get the counterId and counterName value from each object. In order to achieve this first to iterate over each value, and from it you use again the jq to extract each field. After that, you just sed the name with the value in the original file or a copy.

A very quick implementation billow, this will print each time is doing a sed in the file on the standard output the whole file. You should use -i to replace values in place. json.in and yaml.in are the input files having the content you provided.

```
#!/bin/bash

for row in $(cat json.in | jq -c '.[]' ); do
    value=$(echo ${row}|jq '.counterId' )
    name=$(echo ${row}|jq -r '.counterName' )
    echo "$value $name"
    sed -i "s/$name/$value/g" yaml.in
done
```

the output was:

```
- rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.workers.busy"
        to: "apache.200006"  
     ignore_missing: true   
 - rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.workers.idle"
        to:  "apache.workers-idle"
     ignore_missing: true   
 - rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.total_accesses"
        to: "apache.200001"
     ignore_missing: true
 - rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.total_kbytes"
        to: "apache.200002"
     ignore_missing: true   
 - rename:
     fields:
      - from: "apache.status.uptime.server_uptime"
        to: "apache.uptime-server_uptime"
     ignore_missing: true
```